# NameError When asking for user Input

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, input

When I ask for an Input for example:

```
userInput = input('Left or Right? ')
if userInput == 'Left':
    print('okay')
```

And then run the program, type "Left",
This Error shows up:

```
userInput = input('Left or Right? ')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Left' is not defined
```

How can I fix this?

Running Python 3.6.0 on Linux

Comment: Are you sure this is running in Python 3? What happens if you use `raw_input`?

Comment: What rogan said -> you are using Python 2.x even if you think you aren't. `input()` doesn't work that way in Python 3.